# Abbreviated "MY" filters

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, dashboard, calculated-field

I need to save some precious space on my dashboard and need to see the abbreviated version of Month on a "MY" filter. (JAN 2017, instead of JANUARY 2017).

I could achieve this by creating a calculated field with below code:

```
(LEFT(DATENAME('month', [My_Date]), 3) + ' ' + STR(DATEPART('year', [My_Date])))
```

However, the Month/Year values in the filter are sorted alphabetically which is almost useless for my case. I tried to automatically sort the field contents but could not find a way. The only way seems to manually sort the values, which is not a proper solution since new coming Month/Year names will again be mis-sorted in the future.

What might a good solution for my need in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use formatting to display rather than creating a whole new calculation

1. **Click on the date pill**

[image]

2. **Go to Date**

[image]

3. **Click and browse through various formats or create a custom one**
   In your scenario it will be

   `mmm yyyy`

[image]

Comment: When we format a date dimension which is a YEAR on the pill, we do not see custom formats; just **Automatic**, **Four-Digit** and **Two-Digit** options (which makes sense for a YEAR dimension). Even though if we are able to format the pill or format the default property of the field as "mmm yyyy" as you have mentioned, this does not have any effect on the "MY" filter derived from this field.

Comment: Right click on the axis which displays the DATE and click on format. Follow same step as above. See if that helps.

Comment: Since my axis is also YEAR, I get only Auto, Four-Digit and Two-Digit formatting options.